# Difference between savemempool vs getrawmempool information

Tags: json-rpc, mempool

Does the `savemempool`  have any additional information than the `getrawmempool` with verbose=true output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in fact `getrawmempool` returns more information.

`savemempool` saves the mempool contents to disk. However it does not save several things that are precomputed and cached. These values are recomputed when the saved mempool is loaded. `getrawmempool` will provide those cached values.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for answering... will stick with getrawmempool then going fwd